# How to measure elevation or slope along a distance over a Hill-system for height above sea-level?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The equipment includes an Abney level, a 2m Man (at eye level) and a 2m pole.
Methods:
There is a hill-system, and by this I mean the topography of the area rises and falls. This system stretches as long as 800m and the measurements are then taken every 50 metres. The first measurement is then taken at 0-m, at every 50 metres until 800m. The pole starts at 0-m and the man walks a distance of 50m from the pole using the abney level (that starts at 0 Degrees) as a scope to look at the top of the pole to get a degree measurement.

This is done at every point relative to the previous point. So, a(pole) = 0-m, b(man) = 50m. And then a = 50m and b = 100m. And so forth.

for example, if the pole is at 200m and the previous measurement of degree was 10 (from a = 100m, and b = 150m) then the result of this measurement for that distance was a degree of -3. Is it possible to 'correct' a measurement like this on a graph (explained further down

If sea-level is 0-m. Is it possible then to take an elevation profile using just those methods and equipment, and how would the slope be calculated to be used to show elevation above sea-level, or the slope of the bumpy hill-system relative to the previous point?. Such that, if the previous measurement indicate degrees of 1, 2, 2, 10, then -3. If plotted against distance at every 50m, it will only show the elevation from the previous point. [calculated as (tan(degree) x distance x Observer height)] <- *is this the right calculation*

Therefore, 10 to -3 degrees will show a fall below 0 on the y axis when plotted as a line-graph. So, how can this be made to an accurate representation of the height above sea-level? when taking measurements of degree and height from point a to point b at every 50m along a 800m distance.

If the man is at a 20m elevation above sea level at 500m and for the next 150m distance, the degree measurement shows a consistent value of 1, 1, 1, can the elevation above sea-level be measured taking into consideration the methods and equipment measured, without this elevation already being known? Also, what does this method mentioned show? And If I had a separate graph showing the elevation above sea-level to contrast with the graph showing the elevation of point a to b against distance, would this show anything significant?